# Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite. Can't parse json

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I made everything, as here [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). But I have an error

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: 
Value ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿n of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I created MySQL Database and building PHP files on my web hosting.

What is wrong ?

Comment: please post your android code and the String that you got from server.

Comment: And check if the String is encoded as UTF8 especially in your mysql database, you should check the character encoding of both the database itself and the tables.

Comment: JSON data should always be encoded in UTF-8. However, you read it using the ISO-8859-1. If your JSON data contains Cyrillic characters, they will lead to invalid data that can no longer be parsed as JSON

Comment: **@florian**, mysql database encoded at utf8_unicode_ci. **@Sathish D**, I use only latin characters.

Comment: Here you can find the complete working example. http://www.startingandroid.com/registration-and-login-with-back-end-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problem with building the JSONObject from incoming stream.

You can try to decode incoming data before "putToJSONObject" with something like this:

```
try {    
    incomingMsg = URLDecoder.decode(ipnMsg, "UTF-8"); 
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) { 
    e1.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help =(

Comment: How do you parse your JSON response that you receive from your server? Could you show the block?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I need to use JSONArray ? I found many questions of this problem, and many people advice to use JSONArray. But its very interesting for me, why this example doesn't work. I use russian web hosting, but i check main parameters, like encoded in UTF-8. I can't understand where I must look for a problem. In php files or in java code. Or maybe problem in russian web-hosting.